# Go to definition, go to implementation, autogenerate import for Ember

Tags: visual-studio-code, ember.js

Im using Ember with VS Code.

What I need is to generate import string on a fly when I encounter dependency. For example I write someting like:

`@tracked isLarge = false;`

But I don’t have “@tracked” imported yet. So the otion could be to set the coursor on @tracked, press something like “Action + .” and pick “generate import”. It should generate import string:

```
import { tracked } from '@ember/tracking';
```

But it doesn’t work out of the box. How can I do that?

**UPDATE:** the same question about:

1. go to definition
2. go to implementation
3. cmd+click to navigate to implementation/component

Comment: Tracked comes from @glimmer/tracking, which should be in your package.json. auto import for me works about 30% of the time, even on non-ember projects. But having the packages in your package.json is an extra hint that the auto importer can use, rather than relying on implicit deps.

Comment: One way to make auto imports a little better is to use the type definitions for ember, not sure if they work well without ts though. I haven't tried adding them to a js project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"Ember Language Server"` brings some solution. But it works mostly with library code that has `.d.ts` typings.
In case of custom JS code it still doesn't work.

So there is no straight solution. Only 2 ways:

1. Write `.d.ts` typing for custom code JS files
2. Move project to `typescript`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extension [My Code Actions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.my-code-actions)

You can create actions that just insert the text independent of an error.

```json
"my-code-actions.actions": {
    "[javascript]": {
      "import tracked": {
        "where": "insertAfter",
        "insertFind": "^import",
        "text": "import { tracked } from '@ember/tracking';\n"
    }
  }
}
```

The key combo to use is the Code Action combo: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>

If you get a diagnostic (PROBLEM panel, and squiggle) you can use that to further customize the action and you can use text from the diagnostics message.

I'm current adding the possibility to make multiple edits in an action and to use further customization and generalization.

Comment: Looks good, but may be there is something out of the box that generates imports without any presetup.